# android gridview and intent

Tags: android, gridview

I have three class , like this:

```
String[] apps = new String[]{"Bluetooth","ProxAlert","LED"};
```

I use gridview :

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                long id) {

     switch(position){
       case 0:
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),bluetooth.class);
                i.putExtra("id",position);
                startActivity(i);
        break;
      case 1:
                break;Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),proxAlert.class);
                j.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(j);
        break;

       }      
   }
}
```

Do I have another better way to rewrite ?

Comment: i think it´s a good way, but delete the break; in case 1 at the beginning.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
String[] apps = new String[]{"YourPackageName.Bluetooth","YourPackageName.ProxAlert","YourPackageName.LED"};

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,long id) {
      Intent i = new Intent();
      i.setClassName(YourActivity.this, apps[position]);
      i.putExtra("id",position);
      startActivity(i);
   }
 });
```